# Manually set a node to subscribe to a topic

Tags: ros, camera, rqt-graph, topic, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

I was wondering is there any way I can manually make a node to subscribe to a topic?

By checking rqt_graph, the node didn't subscribe to the topic (which I need to set) automatically.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213540/manually-set-a-node-to-subscribe-to-a-topic/) by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2015-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe you should look at this: [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29)

Go to the line 75 of the subscriber node code, and that's what you have to add to the code of your node to subscribe to a specific topic.

---

Originally posted by [S.Prieto](https://answers.ros.org/users/23156/s.prieto/) with karma: 258 on 2015-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on 2015-07-13**:
Oh thanks a lot!